# Geometric interpretations of $||z||_p = 1$?

Tags: normed-spaces

Here $z = a + bi$, with $a, b, \in \mathbb{R}$ and $||z||_p = \sqrt[p]{|a|^p + |b|^p}$.

With $p = 1$, this is just diamond (square rotated 45 degrees) of side=$\sqrt2$ centered at the origin.

With $p = 2$, this is a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin.

As $p \to \infty$, this is a square of side=$2$ centered at the origin.

Is there a geometric interpretation for each integer $p$?

Comment: Is the curve $x^p+y^p=1$ not geometric enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each $p\ge 1$, we have $\|z\|_p=1$ so $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$. Geometrically, this is what happens as $p$ varies:

[image]

(In the limit as $p\to\infty$, the edges sharpen to get a square.)

Comment: Always wanted to see such a graphic!  Nice!  +1!

Comment: This is called a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).

Comment: You need $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$.

Comment: Thanks, @lhf. Never heard that term before! (Oops, will fix abs bars... Typo.)

Comment: How should one formalize these nice graphs? The idea behind it is the inclusion $l^{p}\subseteq l^{q}$ if $p\leq q?$