# The unit ball in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ Consist of two points $a$  and $b$, put $\mu(\{a\})=\mu(\{b\})=1/2$, and let $L^p(\mu)$ be the resulting real $L^p$ space. $\textbf{Identify each real function $f$ on $X $ with the  point $(f(a),f(b))$ in the plane}$, and sketch the unit balls of $L^p(\mu)$, for $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

For which $p$ is this unit ball a square? A circle?.

The unit ball in $L^p$ is:

$$B_1=\{f\in L^p : ||f||_p\leq 1\}=\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\in\mathbb R^2: (|\alpha_1|^p+|\alpha_2|^p)^{1/p}\leq 1 \}$$

(By identification of real functions with points in the plane.)

Is correct my description of the unit ball?

Thank you all.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1038958/52893) might help some with geometric intuition.

Comment: @JohnD; In this case $L^p$ consiste only of the simple functions?

Comment: In the link, the pictures are for the (vector) $p$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I thought it might be a nudge to get you started to help orient yourself.

Comment: @JohnD; Thank you.  And if $\mu(\{a\})\neq \mu(\{b\})$