# Peculiar nature of $x^{22}+y^{22}=1$

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics

We know that the equation of circle is $$x^2+y^2=1$$
Let $a=x^{11}$ and let $b=y^{11}$ so $$a^2+b^2=1$$ should also be the equation of a circle. But you see, desmos says that the equation is of a rounded square. Can anyone please explain me why is this happening$?$ If I'm wrong ( which should be absolutely true) why is this equation drawing a square. In my opinion, drawing a square needs four straight lines or two pairs of lines. Correct me if I'm wrong$?$
[image]

Comment: Is it *not* a square, but for large $n$, the set $|x|^n + |y|^n = 1$ is close to a square . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: This is not a square, it is a peculiar shape with slightly rounded corners and almost (but not completely) straight sides. Now, it _would_ (as you notice) look like a circle in $a/b$-coordinate system, but because you asked it to be drawn in $x/y$ coordinate system it looks the way it does. (The switch from $a/b$ to $x/y$ coordinate system obviously distorts the whole plane.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop can you pls elaborate how the switch takes place??

Comment: Um... Not sure what sort of argument would be persuasive for you, but let me try. You can notice the distortion already in the one-dimensional case. Draw the graph of $a(x)=x^{11}$. On the $x$-axis draw some equidistant points (say spread apart by $0.1$). Map them using the graph to the $a$-axis. Do they stay equidistant?

Comment: @StinkingBishop what distortion??? Isn't it 2 dimensional case as we have two axes?? What does **map them** mean??

Comment: I am not sure how to demonstrate the distortion in the 2-dimensional case so I offer an analogy (1-dimensional case) which you can use to see that there *is* distortion. I am not trying to swap one problem for another, I am trying to use a pedagogical device here / show a simpler version of the same problem. I just have no better idea how to help you. If someone has one, let them speak. As for "map them" I mean take the values $0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,\ldots$ (equidistant) and use the graph of $a=x^{11}$ to find the values $0^{11}, 0.1^{11}, 0.2^{11}, 0.3^{11},\ldots$ and see where they end up.

Comment: Yes. Although $a^2+b^2=1$, the relative rates of change of $a$ versus $x$ are different and the circle shape is not preserved

Comment: See also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038905/42969

Comment: See [this](https://mimmackk.github.io/unitball/#:~:text=The%20unit%20ball%20describes%20the,x%20%E2%86%92%20%E2%80%96%20p%20%3D%201%20.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the family of curves defined by the relation $$(x^n)^2 + (y^n)^2 = 1 \tag{1} $$ for positive integers $n$.  The case of the circle obviously corresponds to $n = 1$.  Your case that you plotted is $n = 11$.

You claim that the two cases should appear the same.  However, a simple argument shows why this cannot be true.  If we look at the intersection of such a curve with the line $y = x$, we find that the relation in Equation $(1)$ above becomes

$$(x^n)^2 + (x^n)^2 = 1, \tag{2}$$

which in turn implies that $$x^{2n} = 1/2,$$ or
$$x = \pm \frac{1}{2^{1/(2n)}}. \tag{3}$$  Therefore, the points of intersection correspond to $$(x,y) \in \left\{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{2}}, - \frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{2}}\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{2}}\right)\right\}. \tag{4}$$  And for $n = 1$, this is just
$$(x,y) \in \left\{ \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)  \right\} \tag{5}$$ but for $n = 11$, we get something obviously different.  Numerically, $1/\sqrt{2} \approx 0.707107$, but $1/\sqrt[22]{2} \approx 0.968984$. The fact that Equation $(3)$ still depends on the value of $n$ means that the curves corresponding to different values of $n$ cannot intersect the line $y = x$ in the same locations.  Therefore, the curves cannot remain the same.

---

On a more fundmanetal level, I think your question indicates a misunderstanding of which variables you are plotting in the coordinate plane, and how transformations between coordinate systems do not in general preserve the geometric properties of curves plotted in those systems.

For example, suppose I asked you to plot $y = x^2$.  This is a standard parabola.  But if I were to use your same reasoning, I could claim that it should be a line, because if I let $a = x^2$ and $b = y$, then we get $b = a$, and the plot of $b = a$ is a line.

But the flaw in that argument is that such a *transformation of variables*, namely
$$(a,b) = (x^2,y)$$
does not need to preserve the geometry of the curves in question.  If I plot $y = x^2$ with $x$ on the horizontal axis and $y$ on the vertical axis, then we get a parabola.  And if I plot $b = a$ with $a$ on the horizontal axis and $b$ on the vertical axis, I get a line.  But the $xy$-plot and the $ab$-plot have different shapes precisely because the relationship between them is nontrivial.  Otherwise, you could claim every curve has the same shape through a suitable variable transformation.  That is of course untrue.

Comment: Ohh i see ${}{}{}$